# What type of question can help expose a quack doctor?

Tags: discussion

Picture this: Doctor **X** claims **Y** and is selling **Z**. And there are some reputable websites that question the credentials of Dr X, refute the claims Y or debunk the cures Z. Folks can search the web for Dr X and "quack" a see some warning results.

What if there are currently no such sources for the layman that shed some medical or scientific skepticism specifically upon Dr X and his remedies? For the case I have in mind, I don't think that either the claims Y or the remedies Z are particularly new, I just don't want people to be conned into buying his snake oils – if that's what they are – if there are no results to web searches for Dr X and "quack".

I should add that I suspect that some of his claims are valid but I question his remedies.

Answer (score 1):

This site tests notable claims. It is not a platform for ruining others' reputations. Ask about claims Y or cures Z, but Dr X is irrelevant, and tangential at best.